# Active Record model's "primary_key" class method returns nil after ruby 2.0 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.0

Just upgraded a Rails project from `ruby-1.9.3-p392` to `ruby-2.0.0-p0`. Everything works fine locally but when I pushed to my staging server on heroku. The `friendly_id` gem is crashing

```
nil is not a symbol

vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/friendly_id-4.0.9/lib/friendly_id/slug_generator.rb:56:in `conflicts'
```

Apparently the User model doesn't have a primary_key class attribute

```
User.primary_key
> nil
```

It should return "id" and works correctly in local dev environment on ruby 2.0 and production environment on 1.9.3.

The rails version is `3.2.13`

Has this happened to anyone before? Not sure what could be causing it. Fresh database restore doesn't seem to solve it.

Comment: Smells like a timing issue but that's just a wild guess. What happens if you instantiate a user before checking `User.primary_key`?

Comment: I'm checking User.primary_key from the console. Instantiating an instance doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Does `User.columns` produce the expected output?

Comment: #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x007f36cf87b588 @name="id", @sql_type="integer", @null=false, @limit=nil, @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @type=:integer, @default=nil, @primary=false, @coder=nil>    primary is false, it's true in local env

Comment: Can you check the database schema directly without going through Rails? Perhaps something changed behind your back and the whole Ruby 2.0 part is a red herring.

Comment: did you try downgrading your staging server?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do this, but does it work if you set `self.primary_key = "id"` in the model?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the commenters are correct and that Ruby 2.0 was indeed a red herring.

Somehow the staging schema got messed up and performing a `heroku pg_backups:restore` was not enough to fix it. This is because it only restores the data.

Doing a `heroku pg:reset` followed by another restore is what eventually fixed it.